# Retrieve database table comments in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, comments

I have created a database table in PHPMyAdmin with table comments. I plan to use the table comments to store table version. I want to retrieve the table comments in CodeIgniter database mysql driver.

I tried to execute the query via the [query](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) method:

```
SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema='{$table}' AND table_name='{$database}';
```

but the it returns nothing. Is there any workaround or proper way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like your question is confusing. 
$this->db->field_data(table_name) Returns an array of objects containing field information.

Sometimes it's helpful to gather the field names or other metadata, like the column type, max length, etc.

Comment: field_data method only returns name, max_length, primary_key, and type.. have you tried to add a table comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_COMMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE
TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$database}' AND TABLE_NAME = '{$table}'";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
print_r($result);
```

And your query is not executing because you have a typo within your query

```
TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$table}'
```

needs to be

```
TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$database}'
```

and

```
TABLE_NAME = '{$database}'
```

needs to be

```
TABLE_NAME = '{$table}'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I might have mixed it out.. my original query works.. `SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema='{$database}' AND table_name='{$table}';
`

Comment: You're welcome. Yep your original query works you have mistakenly mixed those values.